# B&B and simplex algorithm

Tags: simplex, operations-research, branch-cuts

I'm starting studying OR, I read that when solving PLI problem it's common to use Branch and Bound techinque which "decompose" the problem and solves smaller problems. My question is the following: when solving those small problems, is used simplex algorithm? 
The two method are always used together?
Thank you.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to supress tag "branch cut" which deals with complex function theory without connection to (computer science) "tree pruning" ; I have replaced it by "algorithms" which is a generic term...

Comment: Ok thank you, any response to my question?

Comment: I answer by a question : what is a "PLI problem" ? Integer Linear Programming ? Try to avoid the use of acronyms without a full description...

Comment: PLI stands for Integer Linear Programming. When solving a integer linear programming problem, the first step is performing relaxation and solving relaxed problems. I am asking if is simplex used in order to solving those problems